# Z80 Instruction Register Size

Tags: assembly, emulation, z80

I am writing a Z80 emulator and I am confused as to how large the instruction register is.

In the Z80 manual it states that the instructions are from 1 to 4 bytes long, am I given to assume that the Z80 has a 32Bit instruction register? If not then how does it execute instructions like this?

[image]

Comment: There's no instruction "register". The CPU fetches the opcode byte (which in some cases is a prefix), and then fetches the operands based on having decoded the opcode.

Comment: What do you mean by the opcode byte? Isn't that the first/second line under the Operands list in the picture ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no instruction register, and you don't fetch the entire instruction at once. Instead, you fetch it piece-by-piece.

Let's walk through your example instruction:

- Your emulator begins by fetching one byte from the current PC, and increments PC.
- It looks at the byte, which is 0xDD, and the emulator knows that this is the "IX instruction prefix" (because you know this, and therefore have programmed your emulator to know it). Your emulator then fetches another byte to get the actual opcode.
- The opcode byte is 0x36, and your emulator [knows 0x36 prefixed by 0xDD is `LD (IX+d),n`](http://clrhome.org/table/) with the encoding [`0xDD 0x36 dd nn`](http://wikiti.brandonw.net/index.php?title=Z80_Instruction_Set).
- Your emulator then fetches the `dd` and `nn` bytes, writes `nn` to `(IX+dd)`, increments the cycle counter and proceeds to the next instruction.

If you want to write a cycle-accurate emulator things get a bit more complicated, but I wouldn't recommend that if you're a beginner when it comes to emulation.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know about the physical instruction register inside the Z80. What you describe is the abstraction provided by the software emulation.

Answer (score 2):

All it says is that instructions can be 1-4 bytes long. This does not automatically allow an assumption about an instruction register. It says that it is M Cycles: 5. That makes it clear it needs 2 bytes to get the instruction (M Cycles 1 and 2). Then it reads the next 1 byte (M Cycle 3) adds it to the IX register and then it reads another byte (M Cylce 4) which which it then writes to the computed address (M Cycle 5).

Answer (score -2):

Actually the IR register exists, but is not accesible by the programmer. Check the Rodnay Zaks book How To Program The Z80 (page 56). It clearly explains how 1-byte instructions are fetched & decoded, however I still don't get how 2-byte, 3-byte or 4-byte instructions are treated. It would be nice to have a step by step example showing how a 2, 3 or 4 byte instruction is processed using the IR register.

Comment: Too many wrongs here. "The IR register exists", but it has nothing to do with the "instruction register". They are 2 separate registers, each with a unique function, unrelated to "instructions" (the I is for Interrupt, R is for Refresh). "Not accessible", not true: `LD A,R`, `LD A,I` for reading, and the reverse for writing. ".. using the IR register" - plain wrong.

Comment: @Jongware, I beg to differ, if your read the book in question by Rodnay Zaks, he clearly states that the IR (Instruction Register) is indeed a physical register inside the Z80, and it is distinct from both I and R registers (one deals with interrupts, the other with memory refreshing). The IR register is hidden from the programmer, but it is used to store the fetched opcode.